# format verbatim code chunk background colour in bookdown when rendering to PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am writing a guide to using R markdown to include as a chapter in a book written with the excellent bookdown package. I am including verbatim code chunks as suggested in the [R markdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/verbatim-code-chunks.html) by Yihui Xie and Christophe Dervieux. For example:

`````
````
```{r, summary-stats, echo=TRUE}`r ''`
x <- 1:10    
y <- 10:1    
dataf <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

summary(dataf)
```
````
`````

This renders to html fine and displays the code in a code chunk with a light grey background as usual. However, when I render to PDF the code is displayed fine but without the usual light grey background. Can anyone suggest what I need to change to get the light grey background for verbatim code chunks when rendering to PDF?

my sessionInfo

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6     bookdown_0.19    packrat_0.5.0    digest_0.6.25    rappdirs_0.3.1   magrittr_1.5    
 [7] evaluate_0.14    icon_0.1.0.9000  stringi_1.4.6    rlang_0.4.6      remotes_2.1.1    rmarkdown_2.2   
[13] tools_3.6.3      stringr_1.4.0    glue_1.4.1       rsconnect_0.8.16 xfun_0.14        yaml_2.2.1      
[19] compiler_3.6.3   htmltools_0.4.0  knitr_1.28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer fenced code block needs a language name if you want the code block to have a background color in the PDF output, e.g.,

`````
````md
```{r, summary-stats, echo=TRUE}`r ''`
x <- 1:10    
y <- 10:1    
dataf <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

summary(dataf)
```
````
`````

`md` stands for `markdown`, and you can also use ````` ````markdown `````.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Yihui Xie. Works great.